# P9842AB chip data sheet or identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I found this chip whilst looking through some old electronics parts I've been left, does anyone know what it is? I am very new to electronics and a cursory Google gives only opertunities to buy more, no data sheets.

The writing on the top says:
F P9842AB
CD4528BCN

With the first "f" being stylised as if it's a brand.

Here is a picture:

[image: Photo of unidentified IC]

Comment: CD4528 is the important substring.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, this is a

> CD4528BCN Dual Monostable Multivibrator

If you cannot find this (originally by RCA labs), then to convert to the On Semi equivalent number, do this:

New number = **MC1** + numeric value (in this case 4528). There may or may not have been a part made, but in most cases On Semi (as Motorola semiconductor products sector) would have done so at some point.

For MC14528 we can actually find a [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC14528B-D.PDF).

Answer (score 0):

> P9842AB chip data sheet or identification
>   [...]
>   The writing on the top says:
>   F P9842AB
>   CD4528BCN

As *user2943160* has already kindly mentioned in the comments, you were focussing on the wrong part of the numbers on the top. :-)

This is a **CD4528BC** Dual Monostable Multivibrator, made by Fairchild Semiconductor (that's the " *f* " symbol), probably in week 42 of 1998 (hence 9842).

The suffix **N** identifies the package type - in this case, standard plastic dual-in-line (PDIP):

[image: Extract from Fairchild CD4528BC datasheet]
<sub>Source - Fairchild [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4528BC.pdf)</sub>

I can't find the Fairchild datasheet on their website, but the Fairchild datasheet is (currently) available on the Digikey website ([link](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4528BC.pdf)). Other CD4528 manufacturer's datasheets would also likely apply (more or less).

Comment: This will also be the same functionally as the MC14528 (the naming convention for Mot-sps [now On Semi] for their CD4xxx equivalents) https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC14528B-D.PDF